# How do you call functions from a Windows Runtime Component (c#) in a UWP app written in c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, dll, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I have created a UWP app for Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019 that I want to utilize a library of functions when a button is clicked. 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2iOl.png) is the template I selected when creating my UWP app.

I chose to write the library using a [Windows runtime component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeygI.png) written in c# thinking it would be easily imported into my UWP app to where I could call the functions when a button is clicked on the UI. The Windows Runtime component will eventually need to be portable to other software which is why I am creating these two separately. The library has to have the ability to read/write to a USB port which is why I didn't chose Class library template. The class library doesn't allow you to import "System.IO.Ports", but the Windows runtime component does. I have very basic code in my library at the moment so if the Windows runtime component is not what I should be using please offer other suggestions.

I have seen tutorials calling functions from a component in JavaScript, but couldn't find any showing how to call functions from my Windows Runtime Component in a UWP App written in C#.

[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjkCD.png) showing where I would like to call these functions.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMcWf.png) created with XAML

Comment: You are **_much_** more likely to get a good answer if you post your code, particularly if your question includes a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

[VS2010: Use namespace from another project within the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416879/vs2010-use-namespace-from-another-project-within-the-solution)

^^ Figured out I just needed to add reference of Windows Runtime Component to my UWP App.